# Bash Array Subsets by Negative Length

Tags: arrays, bash, parameter-expansion

In Bash, I can use the `${parameter:offset:length}` notation to slice elements of an array, but I can't use it in all the same ways as I would when slicing a string. Specifically, I would like to use this syntax to print all but the last `n` elements of an array:

*note: `--version` output is metasyntax, not the intent of my question*

```
calvin@rose:~ A=($(bash --version |head -1)); echo ${A[@]}
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

calvin@rose:~ echo ${A[3]:0:-8}            # Negative length of substring
4.4.12(1)

calvin@rose:~ echo ${A[@]:2:2}             # Predictable behavior with [@]
version 4.4.12(1)-release                  # Desired output

calvin@rose:~ echo ${A[@]:2:-1}            # Desired input
-bash: -1: substring expression < 0        # Limitation of Bash Arrays?
```

This behavior is defined under [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> If parameter is ‘@’, the result is length positional parameters beginning at offset. A negative offset is taken relative to one greater than the greatest positional parameter, so an offset of -1 evaluates to the last positional parameter. **It is an expansion error if length evaluates to a number less than zero.**

There are two workarounds I currently use:

```
calvin@rose:~ unset A[-1]; echo ${A[@]:2}  # This works, but I lose data
version 4.4.12(1)-release

calvin@rose:~ echo ${A[@]:2: ${#A[@]}-3 }  # This works, but it gets messy fast
version 4.4.12(1)-release
```

Is there a better way? The python `A[2:-1]` kids are making fun of me.

Comment: `echo ${A[@]: -3:2}`? Space is important.

Comment: @Cyrus Clever, but requires foreknowledge of the length of the array. My 'predictable behavior' example would be cleaner.

Comment: `unset 'A[${#A[@]}-1]' 'A[${#A[@]}-1]'`?

Comment: To remove last two elements from array A.

Comment: How does `echo ${A[@]:2: ${#A[@]}-3 }` get's "messy fast"?  `I would like to use this syntax to remove the last n elements from an array` - `A=("${A[@]:0:${#A[@]}-$n}")` ? `unset $(seq -f A[%.0f] $(("${#A[@]}" - n - 1)) $(("${#A[@]}" - 1)))` ? `readarray -t -d '' A < <(printf "%s\0" "${A[@]}" | head -z -n -$n)`? `unset $(printf "A[%s]\n" ${!A[@]} | tail -n $n)`? Any of these are not "messy fast"?

Comment: @KamilCuk maybe we have different ideas about what constitutes clean code.

Comment: Any awk,sed or cut solution is acceptable for you?

like `echo ${A[@]} | cut -d ' ' -f 3-$((${#A[@]}-1))`

Comment: @Edvin Using a subshell and an external proc is far less efficient than my current workarounds.

Comment: I am aware of that ,this is why I not post an answer, and ask instead. I not believe there is a cleaner/shorter solution than you already have.